# HWID Windows - Using Qt Framework

Tags: c++, qt

I am making something that needs to get the HWID of a cmoputer, cross-platform. This is in C++, and I am using the Qt framework with Qt Creator. I really haven't found much on this, so I will explain. I am trying to get the HWID on Windows, and it keeps saying I have unresolved external symbols once I try to compile it. Here is my code for the HWID stuff:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#ifdef _WIN32 | _WIN64//Windows
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
#include <Windows.h>
#define get_hwid() windows_hwid()

#elif defined __APPLE__ //Mac
#define get_hwid() mac_hwid()

#else //Unknown OS
#define get_hwid() unknown_hwid()

#endif

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QMessageBox::about(this, "About", get_hwid());
}

QString MainWindow::windows_hwid()
{
    HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfInfo;
    if(GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfInfo))
    {
        return "we got it.";
    }
    return "couldn't get it";
}

QString MainWindow::mac_hwid()
{
    QProcess proc;

    QStringList args;
    args << "-c" << "ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice |  awk '/IOPlatformUUID/ { print $3; }'";
    proc.start( "/bin/bash", args );
    proc.waitForFinished();

    return proc.readAll();
}

QString MainWindow::unknown_hwid()
{
    return "hello unknown person!";
}
```

This throws these errors:

> mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_GetCurrentHwProfileW@4 referenced in function "public: class QString __thiscall MainWindow::windows_hwid(void)" (?windows_hwid@MainWindow@@QAE?AVQString@@XZ)

and

> debug\MCBruter.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I'm 99% sure the bottom one is caused my the first one, so I would just ignore that.  I have no idea what to do... The Mac one works fine, just the Windows one is giving me problems. Thanks, Hetelek.

Comment: Did you add the following windows library: Advapi32.lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a linker error, caused by the fact that you have included the relevant include file, but you haven't linked your object files against the correct import library. Add `Advapi32.lib` to the libraries to link and the error will go away.

By the way, the correct library to link against for a particular API is always specified in its documentation in the MSDN: if you look at the [page of `GetCurrentHwProfile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724311%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you'll find:

> **Header:** Winbase.h (include Windows.h)
>
> **Library:** Advapi32.lib
>
> **DLL:** Advapi32.dll